# How to create a preview of specific web page?

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, rmagick

I have to create a preview of some web-pages on web-site as image like google search preview. How can i create this on Rails using rmagick or it is impossible?
Thank's.

Answer (score 3):

Use Iframe.[This link can help](http://www.dynamic-tools.net/toolbox/popUp/)

Comment: Thank's for links. Will answer after implementing

Answer (score 2):

Using Ruby ON Rails:

> http://www.cleverleap.com/ruby-thumbnail-generator/
>
> http://blog.cleverleap.com/generate-thumbnails-easily-in-ruby-on-rails/

API's

> http://accidentaltechnologist.com/ruby/programmatically-creating-website-thumbnails/

Free thumbnail creating service:

> http://www.webresourcesdepot.com/10-free-website-thumbnail-generation-services/

Comment: Thank's for links. I needn't third party services, i will create my own plugin. Will use your links and answer after implementing

Comment: You can try the ruby-on-rails link that I have given above, it is not a third-party-plugin, it's a source someone had written, it should help you understand.